# Matplotlib: Curve touches axis boudary. How to solve this?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

I drew this graph using matplotlib using the following code.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [450.0, 450.0, 438.0, 450.0, 420.0, 432.0, 416.0, 406.0, 432.0, 400.0]
y = [328.90000000000003, 327.60000000000031, 305.90000000000146, 285.2000000000013, 276.0, 264.0, 244.0, 236.0, 233.5, 236.0]
z = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]

plt.plot(z,x,'-',lw=3)
plt.plot(z,y,'--',lw=3)
plt.show()
```

As you can see the graph of x touches the axis boundary and does not look good. How can I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `axis`:

```
plt.plot(z,x,'-',lw=3)
plt.plot(z,y,'--',lw=3)
plt.axis([2,20,100,500])
plt.show()
```

Or, use `ylim`:

```
plt.ylim([100,500])
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and the graph did not overlap. Anyway, try to add small margins to the plot:

```
plt.margins(0,0.02)
```

Also you may try to add argument `clip_on=True` to `plot` function call (but it should be set to `True` by default).

Comment: I get the following error when I add this line. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\code\sample.py", in <module>
    plt.margins(0,0.02)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'margins'